Finding the digit position of the first occurance of a string of numbers in the Champernowne constant
The Champernowne constant is 0.123456789101112131415...
What is a more efficient method of calculating the first occurance of a string of numbers within the Champernowne constant? For example: the string "12" first appears at number 1 and index 1 (the decimal point isn't indexed), not the trivial answer of number 12 and index 14. Even though it's there as well, that's not its first appearance in the Champernowne's constant.
Included below is a python script than answers the above problem. Trivially, you can concatenate a looping variable and do an index search of the resultant string. But that is only practical for numbers below 10^7. Examples of this searching method are over on codegolf but none af those scripts can handle large numbers. The scipt below can handle numbers around 10^1000.
For clarification, "x" is imputed number, "n" is whatever number is concatenated to the end of the Champernowne's constant, and "p" is the precise decimal position of the first appearance of "x".
Motivation: this is an interesting problem than is applicable to data compression. Also, I heard people like to search for first occurances of their favorite numbers in pi, for ex. But with pi, a bruteforce search is necessary like is the case an the pi search webpage. Here, it's not.
import random

for f in range(1):
    ax=x=random.randint(0,10**1000)
    minguess=x+1
    print('x',x,'\n')
    d=0
    while int(str(ax)[d])==9:
        ax=int(str(ax)+'0')
        d=d+1
    wx=int(str(ax)+str(ax))
    parsed=[]       
    for g in range(len(str(ax)),0,-1):
        print('check length',g)
        checklist=[]
        for h in range(len(str(ax))):
            wxtwo=int(str(wx)[h:h+g])
            parsed.append(wxtwo)
        for i in range(len(parsed)):
            
            wparsed=parsed[i]
            guess=wparsed-1
            wparsed=int(str(guess)+str(wparsed))
            j=1
            while len(str(wparsed))<len(str(wx)):
                wparsed=int(str(wparsed)+str(parsed[i]+j))
                j=j+1
            if guess==0: guess=1
            check=str(wparsed).count(str(x))
            if check>0:
                if str(wparsed).index(str(x))<len(str(guess)):
                    if guess>0:
                        checklist.append(guess)
            
            wparsed=parsed[i]
            guess=wparsed-0
            wparsed=int(str(wparsed))
            j=1
            while len(str(wparsed))<len(str(wx)):
                wparsed=int(str(wparsed)+str(parsed[i]+j))
                j=j+1
            if guess==0: guess=1
            check=str(wparsed).count(str(x))
            if check>0:
                if str(wparsed).index(str(x))<len(str(guess)):
                    checklist.append(guess)
        
        if len(checklist)>0:
            guess=min(checklist)
            dguess=str(guess)+str(guess)
            for k in range(len(str(guess))):
                wguess=dguess[k:k+len(str(guess))]
                wdguess=wguess+str(int(wguess)+1)+str(int(wguess)+2)
                if wdguess.count(str(x))==1:
                    checklist.append(int(wguess))
            if guess<minguess:
                minguess=guess
                guess=min(checklist)
                q=n=guess
                d=0
                p=0
                while n>0:
                    d=10**(len(str(n))-1)-1
                    m=n
                    n=n-d
                    p=p+n*len(str(m))
                    n=d
                p=1+p-len(str(q))
                l=1
                guesstwo=guess
                while len(str(guesstwo))<=2*len(str(x)):
                    guesstwo=str(guesstwo)+str(guess+l)
                    l=l+1
                p=p+str(guesstwo).index(str(x))
                print('n',guess)
                print('p',p,'\n')
    if x==0: guess=0;p=0
    print('done! \n-------','\nx',x,'\nn',guess,'\np',p,'\n-------\n')
    
#Jesus is Lord

example below is of the dec-encoding of Genesis 1:1:
Further reading about this fascinating constant:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/find-the-number-in-the-champernowne-constant/272674#272674
https://www.kanonical.io/an_interesting_property_of_champernownes_number/
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html
https://youtu.be/BLcneg8ynIM?t=10m45s
Champernowne constant is infinitely long, irrational, transcendental, and normal, and constructed.
I tried the included python script.
One possible improvement method is more sophisticated parsing, like scanning quickly for repeats in the input, thereby sharpening the search space to specific-length solutions.

print(f'{0.123456789101112131415}'.find('12'))? Also, 12 is first found at index 2, not 1.

@OysterShucker index1 is .

Interesting question but I doubt that it has any real applications to data comprehsion

@TalhaTayyab - exactly! and 12 starts at index 2.

Also note that the second instance of 12 is not at index 12 at all, it's at index 14. Both 10 and 11 are two digits, not one.

@OysterShucker, the decimal point isn't indexed. But I did fix the other error that Mike pointed out. Also, I've updated the code.

The only time a number can have an earlier-than-expected index is if it is itself a (truncated) Champernowne sequence: the position for 12 is the same as the position for 1; the position for 56789101 is the same as the position for 5, the position for 100110021003100 is the same as 1001, etc.
So, an efficient algorithm will first check whether the input is itself a (truncated) Champernowne sequence, and if so, will simply look up the index for the first term in that sequence. If it's not, then it's not a subsequence of Champernowne's constant, and its index will be the construction index for the input as full number.
(And of course, the first step just falls through to the second step after throwing away the numbers that don't matter)

nope. for ex: the number 9999 first occurs at Chomernowne number 8999, and at decimal position 34887. Your truncation method doesn't work.

That's an excellent point.

I've tweaked the code if you're interested. It can handle 1,000 digit inputs now.

Just remember not to change the code in your post: that needs to stay the code that has the problem you were asking about. If you come up with a change that solves  your problem (or gets you closer to a solution), write that up as an answer of its own, with an explanation of why the changes work, so you can accept it and others can upvote it in the future. Question posts have to stay the original question post (barring requests for additional details from comments).

I tried a naive version of the algorithm to verify the results, but I noticed a small bug. The algorithm should pick the smallest value for the position (p), otherwise the answer might be incorrect. Here's an example output:
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 
n 192 
p 467 

wparsed 209210211 guess 209 
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 921 209 
n 209 
p 519 

wparsed 209210211 guess 209 
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 921 209 
n 209 
p 519 

wparsed 209210211 guess 209 
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 921 209 
n 209 
p 519 

done! 
------- 
x 921 
n 209 
p 519 
-------

However, the correct behavior should look like this:
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 
n 192 
p 467 

wparsed 209210211 guess 209 
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 921 209 
n 209 
p 519 

wparsed 209210211 guess 209 
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 921 209 
n 209 
p 519 

wparsed 209210211 guess 209 
looking at the checklist:  9210 2109 1092 921 921 209 
n 209 
p 519 

done! 
------- 
x 921 
n 209 
p (minimal) 467 
-------

so I think you can revise it to
p_list = []
# carry out some operations and store the p to p_list
p_min = min(p_list)

